# Javascript - Animation flickers when run multiple times

Tags: javascript, animation

I have created a fairly simple border highlight animation that works great. But when you mouse over it while it is already animating, it totally freaks out.

```
function borderHighlight (x) {
var start = 0;
var end = 255;
var current = 0;
var boo = 0;
var id = setInterval (frame, 5);

function frame() {
    if (current < end && boo == 0) {
        x.style.borderColor = "rgb(" + current + ", " + current + "," + current + ")";
        x.parentNode.style.borderColor = "rgb(" + current + ", " + current + "," + current + ")";
        current ++;
    } else if (current == end && boo == 0) {
        boo = 1;
    } else if(current >= start && boo == 1) {
        x.style.borderColor = "rgb(" + current + ", " + current + "," + current + ")";
        x.parentNode.style.borderColor = "rgb(" + current + ", " + current + "," + current + ")";
        current --;
    } else {
        clearInterval(id);
    }
  } 
}
```

If you want to see it all in action, here's the URL. http://ne.fario.us/projects/writing/

I know this is a similar topic to others here, but I haven't found an answer that suits my specific situation (or at least am not understanding how it fits).

Thank you in advance for any assistance or constructive comments.

Comment: you need to persist the interval id and `clearInterval(id)` at the start. `x.interval=setInterval(frame, 5); ... clearInterval(x.interval)` ; the "debounce" pattern to avoid many animations at once... (calling clearInterval on an invalid id won't hurt anything)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd advise you use of jquery. Your code will be crossbrowser and much much simplier.

Truble with your function is that it runs *several* times while user moves mouse over the div.

Easiest way to fix is to put function call on `mouseenter` event instead of `mouseover`.

But the proper way is to rewrite your function and check before starting animation if animation for this particular div is already started.

In the very begining of your function put this:

```
if (x.hasAttribut('playing')) return; //if animation is playing no need to restart
x.setAttribute('playing', playing); //we put temporary attribute stating, that animation is playing
```

And dont forget to remove attrinbute when animation is finished.